# Composer advantages

Tags: php, composer-php

In our company we currently do not use **composer**, we just download and store all libs under git.

What arguments can be given to our customers and system administrators to convince them of the need to use composer?

Our request must be substantiated enough to make a decision.

Comment: Packages taken via composer often have dependencies. And those dependencies are also taken care of being downloaded by composer. So you get all your dependencies sorted out with simple commands, without ever need to do anything manually, except running `$ composer install` or `$ composer update`. Also you get all package updates without ever needing to delete the old package and replace it with the updated version. Just run the command!

Comment: Don't see why the customers or the system administrators need to care about it? It's more of a development tool, really. It helps you update dependencies easier and you can use composers auto loader etc. (and there's much more advantages than that).

Comment: I find it odd that your administrator have a say in your developing tools. Your customers won't care. Yet the developers might stay sane.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Composer you get the following advantages:

1. The dependencies required by the package you are pulling in are automatically taken care by Composer itself, leaving you free to focus on the programming instead of dependency management.
2. When the package you are using gets a new version, a simple `composer update` will do everything for you without ever needing to do any file management manually.
3. With Composer you get a centralized `autoload.php` file which also be optimized for production. It loads everything you need and all you need to do is include one file. The optimized version is super fast! Simply do `composer dump-autoload -o`.
4. You can use `psr-4` namespaces to load a specific path on your application and have it be included in the autoloader file. Then you can simply `use` the namespace and it's available application wide!

Look at the following URL for a more detailed list of features: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

---

There are a lot more things you can do with Composer and it's wonderful. I highly advise that you guys use it and stop wasting time on managing packages yourself.

Comment: Nice answer! I used composer for a long time, and currently this is about my new company. I just need arguments :)

Comment: @Eddie I'd highly appreciate if you accept my answer if I answered your question! :)

Comment: Accepted, I hope it will help us :)

Comment: Old topic I know - it seems like a great thing to do and I'm intereseted in suggesting it to devs, but are there any cons? How long would it take to implement on a fairly large codebase?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs: many user suffer with installation issues. And I'm still thinking about the economic perspective. Not sure, if there is a cost reduction at all. It brings more complexity into projects. Use with care.

Comment: Using composer [requires a great deal of trust/naivety](https://medium.com/@simonhamp/why-you-shouldnt-trust-your-composer-dependencies-6d417d475ded). You have to assume that all the code it drags onto your server, and that you execute, is always safe.